# How can I determine a matrix when I know a vector and the Matrix-Vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a known Matrix **A** (7 x 4).

I multiply vectors by this Matrix to "encode" the vectors.

In other words, for any 4 element vector u, I know each variable in the equation **A**u = c.

I am trying to create something like the opposite of this Matrix, a Matrix **B** such that, **B**c = u

This would have to be a 4 x 7 Matrix, but I am not sure exactly where to start.

I know that this is possible because **A** is the "Hamming(7,4)" Matrix:

[image: Hamming(7, 4) Matrix]

and so it contains the standard basis generators, I just do not know where to start to create the matrix that "undoes" the encoding process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions to $Au=c$ exist only whether $c$ belongs to the column space of $A$.

When $rank(A)=4$ you can find a **left inverse** $B$ such that BA=I and thus $Bc=u$.

Notably you can construct $$B=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

**EG**

for matrix G the left inverse is

$$G^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}
\frac14 &\frac14&\frac12&-\frac14 &0 &0&-\frac14 \\ 
\frac14 &-\frac14&0&\frac14 &\frac12 &0&-\frac14 \\
-\frac14 &\frac14&0&\frac14 &0&\frac12 &-\frac14 \\
\frac18 &\frac18&-\frac14&\frac18 &-\frac14 &-\frac14 &\frac58 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$